# Struggling to add a properties to an object using a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a for loop to cycle through a list of links and add information about said links to an object.

I have succeeded in using array access within a for loop to add an empty object to my already-existing object:

```
for(let i = 0; i < linksHTML.length; i++) {
    //Add new obj to pageInfo.links
    pageInfo.links["link" + i] = '';
}
```

Returns:

```
pageInfo = {
  currentPageURL: "https://www.volkswagen.fr/fr.html",
  links: {link0: "", link1: "", link2: ""...
  }
}
```

I am struggling however to add properties to the new object like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i < linksHTML.length; i++) {
    //Add new obj to pageInfo.links
    pageInfo.links["link" + i] = '';
    //Add properties to newly created object
    pageInfo.links["link" + i].target = linksHTML[i].baseURI;
}
```

```
let pageInfo = {
    currentPageURL: window.location.href,
    links: {}
}

let linksHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("link");

for(let i = 0; i < linksHTML.length; i++) {
    //Add new obj to pageInfo.links
    pageInfo.links["link" + i] = '';
    //Add properties to newly created object
    pageInfo.links["link" + i].target = linksHTML[i].baseURI;
}
```

I would expect to see

```
pageInfo = {
  currentPageURL: "https://www.volkswagen.fr/fr.html",
  links: {
    link0: {
      target: "https://www.volkswagen.fr/fr.html/somepage"
    }
  }
}
```

However the output is

```
pageInfo = {
  currentPageURL: "https://www.volkswagen.fr/fr.html",
  links: {link0: "", link1: "", link2: ""... <-- Empty object with no new target property
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `pageInfo.links["link" + i] = '';` you are assigning a string, not an object use `{}` instead of `''`

Comment: Wow... That was fast. Many thanks for the help! I was stuck for a while there (noob)

Admins, please can we give this man a medal. He answered the question in 36 seconds!